# Why gcloud doesn't show default forwarding-rules of http?

Tags: google-compute-engine

In Google Compute Engine, after I created a instance with http option checked and can pass through web.
But its forwarding rule isn't shown with "gcloud compute forwarding-rules" in command or "Load Balancing" in console.

*Is HTTP forwarding rule configured as any special rule?*
or anything wrong in my understandings?

Comment: I may be wrong. No forwarding rules are needed. With only a firewall rule it works. `gcloud compute firewall-rules list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP option that you have checked when creating the instance is mapped to a firewall rule in GCE network firewall, which is for incoming traffic on port 80. As such, this will allow incoming HTTP traffic to your VM instance. To learn more about firewall rules you can go through [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls).

The forwarding rules are used for load balancing and protocol forwarding purposes. If you have not configured a load balancer or protocol forwarding the gcloud compute forwarding-rules will not output anything. You can refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/network/forwarding-rules) for more information on forwarding rule.

Comment: OK. I was wrong to confuse the forwarding with the firewall. Your answer is backing my understanding. Thanks.